# Blessed Strike triggered by Word of Radiance

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, area-of-effect

I've seen a few questions regarding Blessed Strikes with various features like second attack or eldritch blast, all of which said Blessed Strikes only affected a single creature because they were separate attacks.

My question is: **How does this work with Word of Radiance if you hit multiple creatures?** Blessed Strikes doesn't say anything about only being able to affect 1 creature, just that you can only deal that damage once per round.

> **Word of Radiance**
>
> Casting Time: 1 action
> Range: 5 feet
> Components: V, M (a holy
> symbol)
> Duration: Instantaneous
>
> You utter a divine word, and burning radiance erupts from you. Each
> creature of your choice that you can see within range must succeed on
> a Constitution saving throw or take 1d6 radiant damage.

> **Blessed Strikes**
>
> You are blessed with divine might in battle. When **a creature** takes damage from one of your cantrips or weapon attacks, you can also deal 1d8 radiant damage to **that creature**. Once you deal this damage, you can’t use this feature again until the start of your next turn.

This wording is consistent with spells like Shatter:

> **Shatter**
>
> A sudden loud ringing noise, painfully intense, erupts from a point of your choice within range. Each creature in a 10-foot-radius sphere centered on that point must make a Constitution saving throw. **A creature** takes 3d8 thunder damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. **A creature** made of inorganic material such as stone, crystal, or metal has disadvantage on this saving throw.

So really, I guess it may come down to whether or not this added damage from Blessed Strikes counts as a single "activation" or if it would be each creature individually. I kind of feel like it would've been easy to specify something like When a "creature takes damage from one of your cantrips or weapon attacks **that target a single creature**...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You choose one creature of those that failed their save to be affected

All that failed their save are eligible (“When a creature takes damage …”) but only one can be affected (“Once you deal this damage, you can’t …”).